# Django not forgetting template name

Tags: python, django

Working with django 1.7, I set template name like this

```
return render_to_response('myapp/search_page.html', args,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

but then i realized i made a mistake, it had to be like

```
return render_to_response('another_app/search_page.html', args,
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Which i changed but now django is always giving me template not found error and is looking for template at `myapp/*.html` instead of `another_app/*.html`

How do i make it forget the wrong name and read new name?

Comment: Delete the `.pyc` files if there are any.

Comment: @alecxe yes i have restarted server but it didnt work

Comment: @SimeonVisser i removed all pyc files, still no luck..

Comment: This might be a very stupid suggestion, but are you sure you are looking at the right places? Look at the stack trace more closely

Comment: Please update your question with the entire error message.

Comment: I solved it like this.. i killed all uwsgi processes, refreshed all symlinks uwsgi/apps-enabled and nginx/sites-enabled, restarted nginx and it was back to normal. So that would mean code was correct and error message was coming from some cache or something. Im still not sure what caused this. So technically i dont have answer to the question yet even though issue is gone.

Comment: well some time it needs restart to work ....

Answer (score 0):

Use `dirs` in the `render_to_response` to find template in other apps. Like this:

```
...
render_to_response('search_page.html', dirs=('another_app',), args, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you may have to provide template directory for  your case. Django will search and match the templates for you.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = [
    "django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader",
    "django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader",
]

TEMPLATE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join("templates"),
]
```